# number of ways to make a pile of $n$ poker chips using red, white, and blue chips and such that no two red chips are together

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> Find and solve a recurrence relation for the number of ways to make a pile of $n$ poker chips using red, white, and blue chips and such that no two red chips are together (consecutive).

**I believe I have found the recurrence relation correctly, however it is solving it where I am running into problems**

**Part $1)$ Find a recurrence relation**

Consider the color of the top chip, if it is red, then he one below cannot be red and the remaining $n-2$ chips give $a_{n-2}$ different ways.

If it is not red, then the remaining $n-1$ chips give $a_{n-1}$ different ways. Then I believe my recurrence relation is

$$a_n = 2a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$$

with $a_1=3, a_2=8$

- If you have two poker chips you have 8 ways to make a pile without
  two consecutive red chips: $wb,bw,rw,wr,rb,br,ww, bb$. Or you
  calculate all possible ways and substract the $rr$ combination: $a_2=3^2-1=8$
- Similar for $a_1$: The are 3 ways without two consecutive red chips:
  $r,b,w\Rightarrow a_1=3$

**Part $2)$ Solve the recurrence relation**

Using the characteristic equation,

$$x^n = 2x^{n-1}+2^{n-2}$$

Dividing by the smallest power gives,

$$x^2-2x-2=0$$

Solving for $x$ gives,

$$x = 1 \pm \sqrt3$$

Then using the general solution:

$$a_n = A_1x_1^{n+1}+A_2x_2^{n+1}$$

Using conditions from above,

$$ 3 = A_1(1+\sqrt3)^2+A_2(1-\sqrt3)^2$$
$$ 8 = A_1(1+\sqrt3)^3+A_2(1-\sqrt3)^3$$

Solving for $A_1, A_2$ I got $A_1 = b=\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{12}, A_2 =  b=\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{12}$

Therefore the final answer would be

$$a_n = \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{12}(1+\sqrt3)^{n+1} + \frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{12}(1-\sqrt3)^{n+1}$$

However an answer I found online to this question is the following, so I am not sure where I went wrong in solving it, looking for some help thanks!

$$a_n = \frac{1}{4\sqrt3}\left[ (1+\sqrt3)^{n+2} - (1-\sqrt3)^{n+2}\right]$$

Comment: A variation on this question was asked, and answered, a year later, April 2019. Other solution methods included the use of generating functions. Link : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173931/solving-a-recurrence-relation-poker-chips/3174071#3174071

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution and the online answer are both correct.  Note that your exponents are one higher than the online answer, so split out the extra factor and note that $$\frac {1+\sqrt 3}{4\sqrt 3}=\frac {\sqrt 3+3}{12},\frac {1-\sqrt 3}{4\sqrt 3}=\frac {\sqrt 3-3}{12}$$

Comment: okay so does the $n>2$ factor into the final answer? so If I stay with my answer I will be correct

Comment: see how the answer online had a negative inbetween so the second term is actually $\sqrt3-1$

Comment: I was unsure if I solved for $A_1$ and $A_2$ correctly

Comment: @user104:  the leading minus would change the numerator at the end to $3-\sqrt 3$ matching your solution.  To check $A_1,A_2$ you can just plug in small $n$ and check.  I believe they are right.  A nit in your solution is that you shouldn't have the $=b=$ in the middle.  You haven't defined $b$ and it certainly is not equal to both $A_1,A_2$

Comment: when I plug in n=1 and n=2 into my solution I get 3 and 8 respectively, so I guess this confirms my solutions for A1 and A2?

Comment: @user104:  yes, it does.  You solved those two simultaneous equations to get them, but your check makes sure you didn't make an error.

Comment: awesome then my answer is correct, thanks so much for your time!