# Solving a recurrence relation (poker chips)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Suppose that you have a large supply of red, white, green, and blue poker chips. You want to
make a vertical stack of n chips in such a way that the stack does not contain any consecutive
blue chips.

I've already found the recurrence relation for $a_{n}$ (where an denotes the number of ways you can make
such a stack of n poker chips):
$a_{n}=3a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}$

But I am unsure of how to go about solving it. After solving it, I'm supposed to consider the specific case where you want to count only the stacks that use exactly 10 chips, and count $a_{10}$ directly.

Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the recurrence relation you have not given the initial values of $a_0$ and $a_1$

Comment: I don't think the recurrence relation is correct. Happy to be told it is; has anyone else checked it ?

Comment: @MartinHansen A quick check shows that the sequence starts with $1$, $4$, $15$, $57$, which indeed does not satisfy the recurrence.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for the confirmation : I've now added an answer based on the correct recurrence relation

Comment: Related; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677958/number-of-ways-to-make-a-pile-of-n-poker-chips-using-red-white-and-blue-chip?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for an interesting question.

The recurrence relation given in the question is not correct, albeit with only a sign error.

It should be;
$$a_n=3a_{n-1}+3a_{n-2}$$ 
$$a_0=1 : a_1=4$$
This gives rise to the generating series,
$$1+4x+15x^2+57x^3+216x^4+819x^5+\dots+169209x^9+641520x^{10}+2432187x^{11}+\dots$$
So, assuming the initial term is $a_0$, $a_{10}=641520$, which you asked for.

This generating series has generating function,
$$\frac{1+x}{1-3x-3x^2}$$
Applying partial fractions to this gives, after some algebra,
$$\frac{1+x}{1-3x-3x^2}=\frac{21-5 \sqrt{21}}{42 \big( 1-\frac{3-\sqrt{21}}{2}x \big)}+\frac{21+5 \sqrt{21}}{42 \big( 1-\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}{2}x \big)}$$
which are recognisable as standard bits directly translating into a formula for the $n^{th}$ term,
$$T_n=\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{5 \sqrt {21}}{42} \right)\left( \frac{3 - \sqrt {21}}{2} \right)^n + \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{5 \sqrt {21}}{42} \right)\left( \frac{3 + \sqrt {21}}{2} \right)^n$$

Happy to elaborate on any of the detail if necessary.

Comment: oh wow, yeah, I totally just wrote down the wrong sign somehow. thank you very much !!

Answer (score 3):

For situations involving linear, homogenous recurrence relations, the characteristic polynomial method works best.

---

Let us have the recurrence relation, for constants $c_i$ and $k>0$,

$$a_n = c_1 a_{n-1} + c_2 a_{n-2} + ... + c_{n} a_{n-k}$$

Much like with ordinary differential equations, we develop a characteristic polynomial for $a_n$. Let $a_n = \alpha^n$. Then we get

$$\alpha^n = c_1 \alpha^{n-1} + c_2 \alpha^{n-2} + ... + c_{k} \alpha^{n-k}$$

Divide through by $\alpha^{n-k}$ next:

$$\alpha^{k} = c_1 \alpha^{k-1} + c_2 \alpha^{k-2} + ... + c_{k}$$

Bring everything to the same side:

$$\alpha^{k} - c_1 \alpha^{k-1} - c_2 \alpha^{k-2} - ... - c_{k} = 0$$

This is a polynomial, and we seek the roots to it. Let them be $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k$. (If $\alpha_i$ is a duplicate root, replace the first duplicate with $n\alpha_i$, the second with $n^2 \alpha_k$, and so on.)

Then, for these roots, up to constants $A_1,...,A_k$ depending on your initial conditions, we have

$$a_n = A_1 \alpha_1^n + ... + A_k \alpha_k^n$$

---

**Footnotes & Caveats:**

As you might imagine, it is hypothetically possible for the recurrence to have complex roots. If you're anything like me, this might present some worry especially for examples grounded in reality. You shouldn't worry too much about these cases. In a sense it all sort of "works out." Since you know one complex number is a root of the polynomial, so is its conjugate. You'll be raising those conjugates to the same power, and thus they remain conjugate. That is to say, for a complex number $z$,

$$\overline{z^n} = (\overline z)^n$$

Thus the conjugation remains and a lot of the "nasty" (imaginary) bits just so happen to negate as a result! A similar thing happens in the example I show in a bit, albeit not so much "complex conjugates" as just the conjugate of a rooted expression.

*(A huge thanks for antkam in the comments for clearing up this detail and resolving a long-standing lack of an intuitive understanding as to how it all "works out" for me!)*

Also, a nice tidbit: it's a good paranoia check to double-check your solution. Once you have the explicit form for $a_n$, check that your initial solutions are valid, and perhaps a few other values you obtain from the recurrence relation. In examples like this where you have to derive the recurrence relation yourself instead of simply being given it, you should be able to get some values by brute force for $n=1,2,3,$ and so on, for ever-how-many initial conditions you need to use. (You need as many initial conditions as there are previous values that determine $a_n$.)

Also bear in mind that this method only works for linear, homogenous recurrence relations. For nonhomogenous ones, I've spoken to you on solving them. For nonlinear ones, we need something more elaborate (such as generating functions) but such discussion is well beyond the scope of this post.

---

A simple example to motivate this method:

> Example: Let us find the solution to the Fibonacci recurrence
>   $$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$$
>   where $a_0 = 0,$ and $a_1 = 1$.

(Bear in mind that while here each $a_{\text{something}}$ has coefficient $1$, they need not be, and as in the previous explanation the coefficients "carry over" to the characteristic polynomial. The Fibonacci relation is simply a common first example.)

Here, the characteristic polynomial is given by

$$\alpha^n = \alpha^{n-1} + \alpha^{n-2}$$

Divide through by $\alpha^{n-2}$:

$$\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1 \implies \alpha^2 - \alpha - 1 = 0$$

This quadratic can be solved by the quadratic formula. It's a well known result that the two roots to this are the golden ratio $\varphi$ and its conjugate $\overline \varphi$:

$$\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2} \;\;\;\;\; \overline \varphi = \frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2}$$

Thus, up to constants $A_1,A_2$, we can claim

$$a_n = A_1 \varphi ^n + A_2 \overline{\varphi}^n = A_1 \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n + A_2 \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n$$

What remains is to determine the constants $A_1, A_2$. To do this, substitute your initial conditions. Thus, you get a system of equations as below. In $a_0$, you let $n=0$ in your solution for $a_n$ above; similarly, $n=1$ in the $a_1$ case.

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_0 = 0\\ 
a_1 = 1
\end{matrix}\right. \implies \left\{\begin{matrix}
A_1 + A_2 = 0\\ 
A_1 \varphi  + A_2 \overline{\varphi} = 1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

To solve this is a fairly typical exercise in solving systems of equations, or linear algebra if you're faced with the awful situation of many initial conditions. I'll skip the boring bits, leaving the algebra to you, simply saying you should get $A_1 = 1/\sqrt 5, A_2 = -1/\sqrt5$.

And thus we get a general formula for the Fibonacci relation!

$$a_n = \frac{ \varphi ^n}{\sqrt 5} - \frac{\overline{\varphi}^n}{\sqrt 5} = \frac{ 1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n - \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left( \frac{1 - \sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n$$

Comment: Short answer for what happens in the case of complex roots: The same analysis goes through, and you get a formula of the form $a_n = a_1 \lambda_1^n + \cdots + a_k \lambda_k^n$ with $\lambda_i$ complex that nevertheless is real for all $n$. (The same complication for repeated roots also applies.)

Comment: Huh. That's actually pretty surprising, though I suppose it makes sense. O_o Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: (1) you had a sign error in your last equation: they cannot both be $\phi^n$ terms. :)  (2) you were not surprised that $A_1 \phi^n + A_2 {\bar{\phi}}^n$ is an integer when $\phi$ is irrational, then why are you surprised when $\phi$ is complex?  Conjugates raised to the same power remain conjugates.

Comment: I was when I originally saw the fact that $\varphi$ was involved however-many-years-ago that was. To a degree I still find it fairly remarkable nonetheless that something so simple could have a solution that looks so complex, with so many irrationals involved, yet outputs integers always. If what I'm saying makes sense.

Comment: And thanks for the correction.

Comment: Oh I remember my own surprise (for the Fibonacci case) decades ago!  All I'm saying is, in both cases, conjugates raised to the same power remain conjugates.  So once you get over one surprise you should not be surprised again.  E.g. in the complex case $\lambda^n, \bar{\lambda}^n$ are complex conjugates for any $n$, so e.g. if their coefficients $a_i, a_j$ are also conjugates then the sum $a_i \lambda^n + a_j \bar{\lambda}^n$ will be real for any $n$.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see what you mean now. Thanks!! I was never really able to figure it out beyond "it just somehow works out," but that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

By induction, your recurrence relation can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_n\\
a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3&-3\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\
a_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3&-3\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_0
\end{pmatrix}
.$$
The Jordan decomposition of this matrix allows for simple closed forms for the coefficients of the powers of this matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a recurrence relation of the form $u_{n+2}=\alpha u_{n+1}+\beta u_n$, you want to find a basis of the set of solutions. One good idea is to look for geometric sequences. If $r$ is the rate, then $r$ verifies
$$r^2=\alpha r+\beta$$
If $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the (complex) solutions, then every sequence is of the form
$$u_n=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n$$
and you find $A$ and $B$ by looking at the initial values.